Python multithreading : How can I share a queue of arguments among already-existing worker objects?
I have a 5 workers ("Processors") that are supposed to process a 100 arguments (maybe in some sort of Queue ?), using a specific method (process()). I want the 5 "processors" to be executed in parallels. I reasearched both concurrent.futures and multiprocessing, but cannot find any example like this
import time
import numpy as np

class Processor :

    def __init__(self, name) :
        self.name = name

    def process(self, arg) :
        print(f'{self.name} : processing {arg}...')
        time.sleep(arg)
        print(f'{self.name} : processing {arg}... DONE')

l_processors = [Processor(f'Processor_{i}') for i in range(5)]
l_arguments = list(range(10))
np.random.shuffle(l_arguments)

# ... what to write beyond this point ?

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance for any answer.
PS :

I have to use these 5 Processor objects, I cannot use a already-made all-wrapped-up "ProcessorPool(n_workers=5)"
I dont want to pre-assign each worker "Processor" to a list of arguments. I cannot know in advance how long each arguments will take (in term of time). Instead, when a worker is free, he should look into the queue of arguments and pick the next one.


Hi, check the manual to concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(). It has an example on how to do this.

Sry, why you can't use I cannot use a already-made all-wrapped-up ProcessorPool? Are you trying to create your own implementation of multiprocessing library?

In this case I would recomment to use Queue: from queue import Queue. Then populate queue with tasks data and every process will connect to the queue to get the next task. Queues are threadsafe and the easiest way to distribute/collect data  if having multiple threads.

Many thanks for your answers ! I am not trying to rewrite my multiprocessing, but each Processor are actually way more complex object, each using a specific IP address for scraping, with a scraping provider, etc... Bottom-line of the story is that I have to use these exact 5 workers

I had the feeling that Queue were the way to go, but I have trouble to understand how to implement 5 workers fetching arguments from the queue in an asynchronous way (cannot find any example)

Simply use q.get_nowait() and in case of error add async sleep await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

I found a way (maybe not the BEST way, I am open to feedbacks) :
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

# populate a Queue of arguments :
q = Queue()
for arg in l_arguments :
    q.put(arg)
    
# creating a pool of Processes : (Manually) :
def make_worker_process_queue(worker, q) :
    while q.qsize() > 0 :
       arg = q.get()
       worker.do_something(arg)
    
l_processes = [
    Process(target=make_worker_process_queue, args=(worker, q))
    for worker in l_workers]

# Making the Processes run in parallel :
for p in l_processes :
    p.start()
for p in l_processes :
    p.join()


this is pretty much how I'd do it, I edited the code slightly to incorporate q.task_done() so you can do q.join() to know when all the tasks are done in case you wanted to do anything extra in the process code.

actually, calling get_nowait() until it throws queue.Empty might make more sense if you are filling the queue before any processes start, as written you have a race condition where if 2 processes check q.qsize() > 0 for the last item in the queue you can end up with a process hanging while it blocks waiting for an item from the queue.

I'm sorry you are using multiprocessing.Queue not queue.Queue so my edit was not applicable, my bad. But the comment about the race condition is probably still applicable.

As I understand it you have an instance worker with some method do_something that takes some argument, arg, and you have N of these arguments that you want to process in parallel using a 5 processes.
The chief problem with your solutions is that the method multiprocessing.Queue.qsize is unreliable (read the documentation carefully) and should not be used. You also need to handle exceptions that may be raised by your worker so that your child processes do not terminate.
You have two approaches you can use. The first uses a multiprocessing.JoinableQueue with daemon processes as follows:
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue

class Worker:
    def do_something(self, arg):
        print('Processing ', arg, flush=True)

def invoke_worker(worker, q) :
    while True:
        arg = q.get()
        try:
            worker.do_something(arg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, flush=True)
        finally:
            # Show work has completed
            q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker = Worker()

    l_arguments = range(10)

    # populate a Queue of arguments :
    q = JoinableQueue()
    for arg in l_arguments :
        q.put(arg)

    # creating a pool of Processes : (Manually) :
    l_processes = [
        Process(target=invoke_worker, args=(worker, q), daemon=True)
        for _ in range(5)
    ]


    # Making the Processes run in parallel :
    for p in l_processes :
        p.start()

    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    q.join()

Note that the above code will run under platforms that use either the spawn or fork method to create child processes (e.g. Windows and Linux).
The second solution uses a multiprocessing.Queue instance and a special sentinel value that is added to the queue 5 times (one for each pool process) signaling that there are no more arguments to be processed:
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Sentinel:
    pass

class Worker:
    def do_something(self, arg):
        print('Processing ', arg, flush=True)

def invoke_worker(worker, q) :
    while True:
        arg = q.get()
        if isinstance(arg, Sentinel):
            break  # No more arguments to process
        try:
            worker.do_something(arg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker = Worker()
    sentinel = Sentinel()

    q = Queue()

    # creating a pool of Processes : (Manually) :
    l_processes = [
        Process(target=invoke_worker, args=(worker, q))
        for _ in range(5)
    ]

    # Making the Processes run in parallel :
    for p in l_processes :
        p.start()

    l_arguments = range(10)

    # For variety, we enqueue the arguments after the processes have been started:
    # populate a Queue of arguments :
    for arg in l_arguments :
        q.put(arg)
    # Add sentinel items:
    for _ in range(5):  # The number of processes
        q.put(sentinel)

    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    for p in l_processes:
        p.join()

